# AIR: make taskbar item flash?

Tags: apache-flex, air

Is there a way to make the taskbar item flash in an AIR app? like it does in other applications to alert the user of a change.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call:

```
stage.nativeWindow.notifyUser(NotificationType.CRITICAL);
```

Just to put some more info, the notification types that can be used here are:

> - NotificationType.CRITICAL: the window icon flashes until the 
>     user brings the window to the foreground.
> - NotificationType.INFORMATIONAL: the window icon highlights by changing color.

There's an article on livedocs about using Taskbar [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=taskbar_1.html)